# Mocking simple parser with existing file and checking it

Tags: java, mockito

I'm starting learning about Mockito. I don't know how to mock my Parser and using existing file e.g "data.txt" with double numbers, but saved as string (21.144 -12.98 etc). And for more I want to check wheter this numbers are not letters or something else. My parser:

```
package model.utils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import model.data.HullPoint;
import model.data.HullPointContainer;

public class Parser {
public static HullPointContainer parseFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    double a, b;
    String da, db;
    double minx = 0, miny = 0, maxx = 0, maxy = 0;
    int k = 0;
    LinkedList<HullPoint> list = new LinkedList<HullPoint>();
    try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);    
        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
                while (lineScanner.hasNext()){
                    da = (lineScanner.next());
                    db = (lineScanner.next());
                    a = Double.parseDouble(da);
                    b = Double.parseDouble(db);
                    HullPoint point = new HullPoint(a,b);
                    list.add(point);
                    if(k == 0){
                        minx = maxx = a;
                        miny = maxy = b;
                    } else {
                        if(a < minx)
                            minx = a;
                        if(a > maxx)
                            maxx = a;
                        if(b < miny)
                            miny = b;
                        if(b > maxy)
                            maxy = b;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                lineScanner.close();
            }
            int i = list.size();    
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println("minX = " + minx +" and minY= " + miny);
            System.out.println("maxX = " + maxx +" and maxY= " + maxy);

            return new HullPointContainer(list, minx, miny, maxx, maxy);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are testing the parser so it is the CUT. You should not mock the CUT, this defeats the object of testing it. I would take a `URI` as input rather than a `File` and store the testcase in the testing classpath. Then you can use the `ClassLoader` to locate it and pass in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

In order to mock your parser you have to create a mock object

`Parser mockedparser = Mockito.mock(Parser.class);`

Then you can tell mockito what to do if `parseFile` method is called. For example:

`Mockito,when(mockedparser.parseFile(myFile)).thenReturn(result);`

and when the `parseFile` method is called with `myFile` as argument, the mock will return `result`

You can `verify` that the method hass benn called:

`Mockito.verify(mockedparser).parseFile(myFile);`

If it has been invoked `once` with this argument, the check will pass, if it wasnt, the check will fail with descriptive error message

PS: Mocking is `simulating` object behavior without having a real instance of the object.
IMHO from your question you should be asking how to `Unit test` your parser rather than `mocking`it